# Ähnlich zu/ wie/ mit

Tags: grammar, preposition

> 1. Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich wie die englische Sprache.
> 2. Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich zu der englischen Sprache.
> 3. Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich mit der englischen Sprache.

Ich frage mich, ob die drei Sätze dieselbe Bedeutung haben.

Comment: 4. Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich der englischen Sprache. (Eher: ... ist der englischen Sprache ähnlich).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grammatikalisch sind alle drei von dir genannten Sätze falsch.

Richtig sind folgende Konstellationen:

> - Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich der englischen Sprache.
> - Die deutsche Sprache ist der englischen Sprache ähnlich.
> - Die deutsche Sprache ähnelt der englischen Sprache.

Bei *ähnlich* handelt es sich um ein Adjektiv, das **keine Präposition**, sondern **direkt einen Fall** verlangt und zwar den Dativ.

Siehe zum Beispiel [diese Quelle](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/adjektiv-adverb-rektion/adjektive-die-kasus-direkt-regieren/).

---

Wie in den Kommentaren angemerkt, ist folgende Variante (der in der Frage erste Satz) **nicht** grammatikalisch richtig, wrid allerdings umgangssprachlich am häufigsten verwendet:

> - Die deutsche Sprache ist ähnlich wie die englische Sprache.

Comment: Und die umgangssprachlich gebräuchlichste Form dürfte *...ähnlich wie die englische Sprache...* lauten. Nicht **richtig**, aber viel gebräuchlicher als die genannten Formen.

Comment: @tofro ich habe es in der Antwort ergänzt.

Comment: @tofro : Eine Frau benutzt "mit" anstatt eines "wie"

Comment: Aus irgendeinem Grund würde ich „so ähnlich wie“ sagen.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 *...ähnlich mit...* könnte eine regional verbreitete Verwendung sein - Hier im Süden höre ich sowas nie jemand sagen.

Answer (score -1):

Kann man auch sagen: "Die deutsche Sprache ist der englischen Sprache ähnlich."

Comment: Ist es sicher? Zu mir scheint es nicht wirklich korrekt.

Comment: Das ist richtig, wurde aber schon von jera in [der akzeptierten Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/29275/5398) in der Liste der richtigen Möglichkeiten erwähnt - als zweiter Punkt.

Comment: Ist das eine Frage oder eine Antwort?

Answer (score -4):

Alle drei Sätze würden verstanden werden. Ich als Deutscher hätte gar nicht bemerkt, dass da ein Fehler sein soll.

Comment: Ja, wenn man die Schule nicht besucht hat.