Was ist die richtige Übersetzung von „it is similar to that"?
Eine sehr einfache Frage, aber eine, die ich in diesem Moment nicht beantworten kann.
Ich möchte folgendes ins Deutsche übersetzen:

It is similar to that which we have mentioned earlier.

Oder so etwas Ähnliches.
Ich weiß, das man „er ist seiner Schwester sehr ähnlich" sagen kann.  Das heißt, dass ähnlich mit dem Dativ geht. Könnte ich also folgendes sagen:

Es ist dem ähnlich, was wir vorher erwähnt haben.

Ich habe DeepL benutzt, um dessen Antwort zu sehen. Es hat folgendes produziert:

Es ist ähnlich wie das, was wir bereits erwähnt haben.

Ist das eine korrekte Übersetzung?  Ist das die beste?  Was würdet ihr sagen?

Ich habe diesen Link gefunden: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/%C3%84hnlich-zu-wie-mit
Das hat mir geholfen - wir „user unknown" sagt, ist „ähnlich wie" eher eine umgangsprachliche Verwendung...

This sentence contains references to phrases with unknown morphological attributes, so you must give the context for determining the right inflection in the answer.

Viele Übersetzungen sind möglich für:

It is similar to that which we have mentioned earlier.

Etwas elaboriert:

Das ist ähnlich dem bereits Erwähnten.

Mehr umgangssprachlich:

Das ist ähnlich wie das, was wir bereits früher erwähnten/erwähnt haben.

Der Satzbau kann aber auch umgestellt werden:

Das ist dem bereits früher genannten ähnlich.


Eine Variation von "ähnlich wie", die einem gelegentlich über den Weg läuft, ist "so ähnlich wie": "Das ist so ähnlich wie das, was...". Diese Variante ist noch ein klein wenig stärker umgangssprachlich als "ähnlich wie".

Das sind beides korrekte Übersetzungen. Es gibt auch viele andere korrekte Übersetzungen dafür. Interessanterweise hast du eine davon in deiner Frage bereits verwendet: "so (et)was Ähnliches" ist eine häufige Phrase, die man z.B. im Satz "das ist so etwas Ähnliches wie das, was wir vorher erwähnt haben" verwenden kann.
Man beachte jedoch: "bereits" = "already", "vorher" = "earlier", "previously"; das ist ein subtiler Unterschied.

Neben den Varianten in den anderen Antworten gibt es noch das Verb ähneln, das ich hier als eleganter und idiomatischer empfinde:

Das ähnelt dem, was wir vorher erwähnt hatten.

